# customizing header in Communities (Winter 18)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, napili, winter18, lightning-bolt

Prior to winter 18, we were able to customize the display of the pageHeader image by referencing the class `.no-assigned-image` in our markup.  We used this to create a custom theme and provide our customers with the ability to control things from a single location.

Today, I deployed into a new sandbox.  What I now see is that there is no header image in our custom theme.  If I switch the theme back to Napili, the header shows up.

Investigating it a bit more, what I am seeing is that the markup for the header in Winter 18 Napili has changed significantly and the CSS we used to rely on doesn't appear relevant anymore.

It looks like now, the background image is driven through `.siteforceServiceBody .cHeaderPanel`   That cHeaderPanel makes me think they moved some of this stuff into a lightning component that gets the background image somehow.   I also noticed the  CSS is originating from `<style></style>` tags instead of from app.css, now.  I'm not sure if that is new, or reflective of some architectural change in direction, but I don't see it in the previous template.

Can anyone point me in a good direction for troubleshooting this?  My hope was that perhaps the pageHeader existed as a token now, but I don't see any evidence supporting that.   I'd really like to be able to continue to leverage the existing image upload functionality that the branding editor provides, but we need to be able to have control over the header.

Comment: Just to let you know there is currently a known issue about background color / image being overridden in Community in Winter '18: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018Au5QAE&title=background-color-or-image-is-overridden-when-using-community-theme-in-winter-18

Comment: That was the first thing I tried.  Unfortunately, this isn't the problem in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Re: ability to reference the Header Background image in the Customer Service (Napili) template**

If you need to reference the Header Background Image using the Customer Service (Napili) template the cleanest way to reference it is through this approach:

1) Create a defaultTokens bundle (or update your existing one) to include:

```
    <aura:tokens extends="force:base">
      <aura:token name="headerImageUrl" value='' />
    </aura:tokens>
```

2) Target the following CSS Selector:

```
.headerImage {
    background-image: t('url(' + headerImageUrl + ')');
}
```

*Please note that this is not a 'supported' selector/token today so there is the potential that it could change in the future (although we will do our best to communicate any changes/updates in the Customer Success and Partner Community chatter groups)*

For anyone looking to reference the Branding Logo Image we are introducing a supported design token: brandLogoImage

**Re: not being able to Save changes to a record**
This is a known issue and is being fixed ASAP before Winter '18 rolls out to Production. Apologies for the issues that this has caused in Sandbox/DE Orgs.

Cheers - D Green (Community Cloud PM)

Comment: Thanks, David.   This worked and our front end guy confirmed it.   I'll have to keep a closer eye on the Partner Community chatter group.

Comment: Absolutely. I realize that these are not ideal changes to spend your time on so we are working to address many of these in the near future. Thanks (as always) for being part of our Ohana.

Answer (score 3):

There is no Styling guide for customizing lightning communities, and Salesforce 
recommends using CSS sparingly and only when necessary,
since all future releases of template components might not support all CSS customizations you do. In summer 17, the header was scoped under cHeaderPanel,

I have found that the main classes for identifying the different component sections of the napili template layout have a certain syntax cNameSection

For Example:

> - cHeaderPanel
> - cHeaderLine
> - cBrandingProfile
> - cSearchPublisher (Search and Post publisher Searchbox)
> - cNotifications
> - cProfileCon
> - cNavBarCon
> - cCenterPanel
> - cFooterPanel

[Using Templates to Build
Communities Summer 17](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/community_templates.pdf)

If you have customizations that depend on CSS, I would strongly recommend you create a [custom theme layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm) with your own CSS classes where you will be able to have control over them.

Comment: I got some custom CSS(for cHeaderPanel, cCenterPanel and few others) in my Summer'17 Napili's template, which are almost(completely) obsolete in Winter'18 Napili. I know this sucks, but I have to see if I can get some work-around. You know what, standard **Save** button functionality is not working to save a record. Huge blow to my community.

Comment: yeah, that's why you would want to create your custom Theme, to avoid running into these issues

Comment: Here is the issue I am facing in WI'18 Napili's community: [Salesforce Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCR2QAM)

Comment: Creating custom theme? How would I do that? My understanding is: Create a community using Standard template(whatever we choose when creating) and make our custom components.

Comment: i linked the doc for reference purposes

Comment: Alright bud, my head goes somewhere else now. I am pretty pissed with this **Save** button issue. That's just the basic standard functionality. They rolled over a new release and broke this standard functionality. End users see this as a development failure rather than a Salesforce Issue. All they see is a website that is not saving a record.

Comment: We're fine building a custom theme layout.  In fact, we have been doing that for the past year.  The problem is just that we hoped to use the upload ui in the builder to load the header image rather than having to reference a static resource.   Since the image is defined in the css, we were hoping to piggyback on the Salesforce css to grab the same info but then modify it to suit our purposes.

Comment: not a good idea, you will have to fetch the images from org assets using apex and reference them through attributes in you theme layout

Comment: adding to that, I would say that the main problem is that we want to get the header image.  I really couldn't care less if we are piggybacking on the CSS class.  In fact, I'd much prefer a token that we can reference in the `background`  declaration instead of having to use a hack, which you correctly identify as a risk for breaking in the future.   Then we could just build it exactly how we want it.

Comment: ahhh, wait a minute, i think you  can use tokens to reference them =P they are all referenced [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/design-tokens/)

Comment: nope, my bad, not the images, sry

Comment: thanks for the effort, though!   That's a good resource - a little more organized than the developer notes.   I'll have to talk out some other possible solutions with my colleagues.  Appreciate your ideas.